# What does なんと mean here?

Tags: particles, adverbs

I'm reading this introduction to mahjong, and found this use of なんと I cannot match to anything in Daijisen.

> １回目のツモがまったく関係ない西で、そこでローワンをアンカンしたら、なんとリンシャンからイーソウをツモ。

As I understand it, the line means something like:

> The first draw was the useless 西, but then you used the 6 of characters to form a *kan,* and the replacement tile you drew was the 1 of bamboos [which got you into *tenpai.*]

But where does the なんと fit in here? How does its presence affect the sentence?

[image: screenshot]